# Writing $11$ by sum of $3$s and $1$s

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, diophantine-equations

We want to find number of ways for writing $11$ by sum of $3$s and $1$s. For example $11 = 3 + 3 + 3 + 1 + 1$ and $11= 1 + 3 + 3 + 1 + 3$ are two ways for writing $11$ . I tried to use the diophantine equation but I don't know whether it is useful or not . It is very hard to write all of them situations . Also if there is a general way for questions like this , I will glad to know it .

Comment: You can do 11*1, 3+8*1, 2*3+5*1, 3×3+2*1. Then use the permutations function if 1+3... and 3+1... are different.

Comment: Do you know a general formula for it ?

Comment: Nope. Sorry bro. You could find it though. Could be fun.

Comment: Okay , Thank you . Do you think diophantine equation here is irrelevant ?

Comment: Yes 3a+b=11 in the first quadrant.

Comment: Seems pretty irrelevant to me.  As an aside, you could also approach this via recurrence relations.  Similar to the recurrence relation $a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$ with $a_0=1,a_1=1$ as the number of ways to write the number $n$ as the sum of $1$'s and $2$'s (*or the number of tilings of an $n\times 1$ grid with dominoes and monominoes*) you have for your specific problem the recurrence relation $a_n = a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}$ with $a_0=1, a_1=1, a_2=1$.

Comment: Sorry but can you explain more ?

Answer (score 2):

**Generating function approach**

If $a_n$ is the number of ways to write $n$ as the sum of $1s$ and $3s$, then $a_0=a_1=a_2=1$ and $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+a_{n}$. If $f(x)=\sum_{n} a_nx^n$ then $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x-x^3} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (x+x^3)^k$$

If $k$ is even, then there is no $x^{11}$ term in $(x+x^3)^k$. When $k$ is odd, you need the coeffient of $x^{11-k}$ in $(1+x^2)^k$, which ie $\binom{k}{(11-k)/2}$.

Letting $k=2j+1$, the result is $$\sum_{j=0}^{5} \binom{2j+1}{5-j}=\binom{1}{5}+\binom{3}{4}+\binom{5}{3}+\binom{7}{2}+\binom{9}{1}+\binom{11}{0}$$

Basically, $k$ is the number of values in the sum, which must be odd since the sum must be odd. Then $(11-k)/2$ is the number that must be $3$, and $\binom{k}{(11-k)/2}$ is the number of ways to place that $3$s in the sum.

Comment: Can you explain why $a_0 = 1$ and $a_{n+3} = a_{n+2} + a_n$ ?

Comment: @S.H.W. in the same way as in the proof for [tiling a $2\times n$ board with dominoes](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~academicoutreach/docs/fibonacci-numbers-and-tiling.pdf), here we make the analogy to tiling a $1\times n$ board with $1\times 1$ pieces (monominoes) and $1\times 3$ pieces (triminoes).  We notice that any tiling of length $n+3$ will either end with a monomino and be preceded by some tiling of length $n+2$ (*of which there are $a_{n+2}$ such tilings*) or end with a trimino and be preceded by some tiling of length $n$ (*of which there are $a_n$ such tilings*).

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you but I can't understand why $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+a_{n}$ is true . Can you provide a proof ? Also I think $a_0$ should be zero .

Comment: @S.H.W. there is *one* way to fill a non-existant board.  Just because the board is of length zero doesn't mean that the number of ways is zero.  If that is unsatisfying of an explanation, then ignore the existence of zero and instead define your initial values as $a_1=a_2=1$ and $a_3=2$ instead.  (*note, our original definition will give $a_3=a_2+a_0=1+1=2$ anyways*).  As for a proof as to why $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+a_n$... I already gave it.  All ways to tile a $1\times (n+3)$ grid with monominoes and triminoes will either end in a monomino or in a trimino, contributing $a_{n+2}$ and $a_n$ resp...

Comment: @JMoravitz So why we are not counting it twice ? $a_{n+3} = 2(a_{n+2} + a_n)$ . As you wrote we have two ways .

Comment: @S.H.W [let us continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58977/room-for-shw).